# Why RDP option not visible in GCP console for windows VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have one datadisk(Windows) by using that disk I have created the VM in GCP console but when I am trying to connect the instance from GCP console, 
instead of RDP option it is showing as SSH option.Can any one help me to resolve the issue.

Note: I am able to do the RDP for that VM from out side.

Comment: It seems that this issue happens when you create the instance from a custom image (in your case a disk), and there is a already a report addressing it at this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67889374).

Comment: I just tested it, and it worked fine for custom images that are originated in GCE. So I assume that your image was migrated. Thus, the link above