# How do I export a copy of a VM Instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to export a copy of a VM Instance which is a Windows 2012 R2, so that someone else can load that exact same instance with the same files and logins, and run it from their own Google Cloud account.

How can I export my VM Instance so someone else can load the exact same on their Google Cloud and run it exactly how I have created?

Answer (score 0):

To use resources from one project to another you need to give read access to the ressource you want to share following this guide: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects

In your case you will want to make a snapshot of you compute and share it or if you can do an image of your compute instance and share the image.

Comment: I have tried to send an image of the instance already. However, when the other user created an instance using the image through the Custom Image option, they were unable to boot into the actual Windows server through RDP. There was no option for RDP access.

Comment: So you already know how to share the image, do you have issues using the image yourself or does it work well in your project?

Comment: I was able to share the image, but when the other user creates an instance using the image, it does not allow RDP connections for some reason. I think it may be because it is not registering as a Windows 2012 R2 server. It works perfectly in my own project. I want the other user to actually be able to RDP connect to their VM with my image.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zt5ym9c

Here are some images that further reiterate my problem.

Comment: Could you try doing the same with a linux image (Debian or other) and see if you have the same issue? Maybe it's something specific with Microsoft Server in relation to the licence?

Comment: As mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52643247/why-rdp-option-not-visible-in-gcp-console-for-windows-vm), it was working fine for me. I created the image in my original project from a boot disk using sourceImage: "projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-server-2012-r2-dc-v20180911" which source image your original project’s boot disk was created from? You can find that information by executing this command in [cloudshell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/) gcloud compute disks describe [diskname] --zone [diskzone] --project [originalproject] | grep sourceImage

Comment: sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-server-2012-r2-dc-v20180814
sourceImageId: '4026302984913286073'

This is what I get when I ran that cloudshell command.

Comment: I tested the image provided, and that also worked fine without issues. I created an instance from it in one project, installed some applications, and then I shut it down. In console, I created a custom image from the boot disk, and from a different project I created a new instance from the custom image (in my original project), and when I RDP'd to the instance, the application worked also. Could it be that you created the image from a data disk and not the boot disk? or that the user did not build the instance from the correct custom image ?